# Is a node.js module instance created for each require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am trying to solve a bug in a `node.js` application.

In a module called `mmm`, I have a local variable (not exported) called `xxx` which is set to `false`. There is an exported function called `enableXXX()` which sets the variable to `true`. Another module `nnn` requires `mmm` and calls `enableXXX()`.

Other modules require `mmm`, but it seems that the call to `enableXXX()` has not been performed. It behaves as if `xxx` is still `false`.

Do it mean each require create a separate instance of the module?

**Update**

I turns out it was a wrong upcase letter in a require:

```
// Module A
var XXX = require("./myDir/xxx.js");
...

// Module B
var XXX = require("./mydir/xxx.js");
...
```

Comment: yes, require makes a new instance and a new clean lexical local scope.

Comment: If you see the problem with the code, that you suppose is not executed, you should debug. Place breakpoints and see if they are executed. If you can't place breakpoints output some text after some lines and find which lines are executed and which are not.

Comment: @dandavis ok thanks, if you create a solution, I will approve it

Comment: @dandavis High quality trolling instanceof High quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the node documentation. You should read the section about caching AND the caveat section: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Comment: It is definitly a module caching caveat issue.

Answer (score 11):

No, it doesn't. Let's make an experiment:

**mmm.js:**

```
var xxx = false;

exports.enableXXX = function() {
    xxx = true;
}

exports.isEnabled = function() {
    return xxx;
}
```

**nnn.js:**

```
require('./mmm').enableXXX();
```

**main.js:**

```
require('./nnn');

console.log('The result is: ' + require('./mmm').isEnabled());
```

**Now let's run `main.js`:**

```
$ node main.js
The result is: true
```

**And here is an explanation from [the official docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):**

- Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get **exactly the same object returned**, if it would resolve to the same file.