# How to solve module caching caveats in node.js (singleton issue)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, singleton

Following another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125459/is-a-node-js-module-instance-created-for-each-require/24125773), I understand I am facing a [module caching caveat issue](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching). Obviously, several instances of the same module are created in my project.

I am requiring the module from other modules located in different folders:

```
var mm = require("./myModule.js");
...

var mm = require("../myDir/myModule.js");
...

var mm = require("../../MyDir/myModule.js");
...
```

I have been trying to create a unique instance of `myModule` (singleton) using an object and by exporting it:

```
var myModule = function() {

    if (!(this instanceof myModule)) { return new myModule(); }

    ...

};

...

module.exports = new myModule();
```

Yet, it does not solve the issue. What is the right way to declare a singleton in node.js? And how to retrieve the instance in other modules?

Comment: the caveat section refers to packages in `node_modules` folders, it's not your case

Comment: @vkurchatkin: my tests show that there are two instances of the module created... it is my case...

Comment: can you post full example?

Comment: Also, are you on windows?

Comment: I am on windows, I am currently trying to create a simple example. You think this could be a slash/backslash issue?

Comment: In the simple example, I don't see the issue. Yet, in my application, it happens.

Comment: it's likely to be case insensitivity issue, see https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6000

Comment: It was, if you create a solution, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Windows issue: file paths in Windows are case insensitive, so `./File.txt` and `./file.txt` refer to the same file. The problem is, that node is not aware of that and uses resolved file paths as cache keys, so it's possible to load same module multiple times using different casing.

More about that issue and discussion: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6000

Solution (kind of): don't use upper case in file and directory names inside node projects

Answer (score -2):

That pattern definitely works for a singleton.

```
// singleton.js

module.exports = new Singleton

function Singleton () {
  this.rand = Math.random()
}

// one.js

var singleton = require('./singleton')
console.log(singleton.rand)

// two.js

require('./one')
var singleton = require('./singleton')
console.log(singleton.rand)
```

Sure enough consistent output.

```
0.7851003650575876
0.7851003650575876
```